# Angular - Expose variable to Controller

Tags: angularjs, scope, controller, factory, encapsulation

So I have a controller that makes a call to a factory and then sets a "variableToExpose". When I console.log($scope.variableToExpose) is comes up as undefined. Whats the best way to expose that variable to the controller?

```
.controller('SomeCtrl', function($scope, $http, $state, SomeFactory) {

  console.log($scope.variableToExpose); //returns undefined

  SomeFactory.getRequest($id).then(function(response){
      $scope.variableToExpose = varFromGetRequest;
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You're trying to print the value of the variable before even executing the code that defines it. What do you expect? And even if it was after that code, the request is asynchronous. Put that code inside the callback function, after the line which defines the variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the `console.log` inside the success handler.

```
app.controller('SomeCtrl', function($scope, $http, $state, SomeFactory) {


  //console.log($scope.variableToExpose); //returns undefined

  SomeFactory.getRequest($id).then(function successHandler(response){
      //$scope.variableToExpose = varFromGetRequest;
      $scope.variableToExpose = response;
      console.log($scope.variableToExpose);
  });
});
```

The `.then` method of a promise invokes the success handler function after the promise has resolved. The `$q` service invokes that function with the resolved value of the promise as the only argument.

Comment: thanks for the response! The thing is I'd like to access the variableToExpose where I originally have the console.log()

Comment: In that case use the `Timemachine` API. But beware that leaks can cause ripples in the spacetime continuum.

Comment: very funny ... there must be another way to do this :)

Comment: @Andres No there isn't. You can't know what the response of an HTTP request contains before sending the request and receiving the response. If you can, then there is no reason to send the request in the first place, is there?